# system time in specific format in c program

Tags: c, time, systemtime

I am using RED HAT machine. I suppose to get system time in my program.below is a part of a code.
`date=%Y-%m-%d time=%H:%M:%S` is the format I wants.
issue is it is giving me GMT time instead of my current system time.
how can I get `system time` in this format?

```
char *buf_cur = buf;
    char timestr[TIMEBUF_SIZE];
    time_t now = time (0);

    strftime(timestr,TIMEBUF_SIZE, "date=%Y-%m-%d time=%H:%M:%S", localtime(&now));
    buf_cur += sprintf(buf_cur, "%s",timestr);
```

in short I want a time which "date" command gives in linux. with above format.

Comment: according to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html) the timezone should be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

The `localtime()` function converts the calendar time timep to broken-
       down time representation, expressed relative to the user's specified
       `timezone` i.e. `GMT`

To get time in `UTC` , you should use `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS time is set to the local time at the machine location **and** the time zone is set to location's time zone, then the code you show should give you local time.

- Check/[adjust](http://www.redhat.com/advice/tips/timezone.html) the machine's time zone.
- Check/adjust the time set in the machine's BIOS

Comment: can you explain me in detail ? I am a bit new to it.  for example I have two  machines. one in africa and one in india , now both have different time. so I just want time which is current time of the machine. lets say what "date command" give. with this format

Comment: both will not have different time.they will show time according to your machine's set timezone.
Can you give output of both your program & output of date command?

Comment: @user95711: Please see my adjusted answer.